# Do the improper integral exists

Tags: real-analysis

Write
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$ if I split it in two
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx  + \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx.$$
If first integral diverges and the second one converges can I say that the following improper integral exists?

Comment: No. It exists if and only if *both* integrals are convergent.

Comment: In layman terms: $A$ (value unknown) is $B+\infty$ ($B$ is finite) then $A=B+\infty \Rightarrow A=\infty$.

Comment: @vitamind Diverging to $+\infty$ is not the only way the integral can fail to converge

Comment: @SolubleFish I am well aware of this :). Please note my first comment "In layman terms", so please consider this an unrigorous example.

Comment: @vitamind Very nice the "In layman terms" that I not know.